# Parallels in the planes: Differences between horizontal and vertical

Tags: geometry

Why are all horizontal planes necessarily parallel, whereas all vertical planes are not? (vertical planes being *possibly* parallel, but not *necessarily* parallel)

In different words: how is it possible for vertical planes to intersect while it is impossible for horizontal planes to intersect?

Comment: Hi! Can you please add any reference to your question? Thank you.

Comment: No reference really, just a thought experiment ...

Answer (score 2):

This is just matter of definition. We have only 1 vertical dimension and defined horizontal planes as all planes orthogonal to this vertical line. But we have 2 horizontal dimensions so vertical planes are those who orthogonal to horizontal PLANE not a line. This is why our vertical planes are not defined in the same way and then can intersect. It is about how we formalize 3D space.

Comment: Ah yes, a matter of definition.

I suppose the roots of this question then dig into why there are two horizontal dimensions while only one vertical dimension.

But then again, just a way to formalize 3D space. Thanks.